# How do I find out which file(s) an app is trying to read at launch?

Tags: crash, markdown

The other day [MultiMarkdown Composer](http://multimarkdown.com/) started crashing on launch, and I can’t get it to stop. (The app appears in the dock and then immediately crashes again.)

I have tried:

1. Deleting the app and reinstalling it
2. Deleted files and folders:

   - ~/Library/Preferences/com.multimarkdown.composer.mac.*
   - ~/Library/Application Support/MultiMarkdown Composer/
   - ~/Library/Caches/com.multimarkdown.composer.mac/
3. `open -F -a 'MultiMarkdown Composer'`

   - -F  Opens the application "fresh," that is, without restoring windows. Saved persistent state is lost, except for Untitled documents.

Trying to app in a separate user account *works*, so it has to be something related to my user account, but I can’t figure out what.

The developer looked at the crash logs and they indicate that it’s trying to read a file when it starts up, but the logs don’t show which file.

So I am trying to find out what files/folders are being accessed when the app is being launched, thinking that might lead to a solution.

What tools are available to do that, and how should I use them?

I tried `sudo fs_usage -w -f pathname -f filesys` but that didn’t appear to show anything useful.

Any other ideas?

*(This is on Mac OS X 10.8.5)*

Answer (score 2):

Try using `opensnoop`:

```
sudo opensnoop
```

(You can also use `-n` to specify the process name, but it doesn't work with arguments that contain spaces by default. To fix it, replace `"'$pname'"` with `"'"$pname"'"` in `/usr/bin/opensnoop`.)

You could also try to delete files in `~/Library/Containers/` or `~/Library/Saved Application State/`.